# Example of a function with exactly two horizontal and vertical asymptotes, and an odd function with its absolute maximum value at exactly two points?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, asymptotics, maxima-minima

A while back a person posted this question on this site. I played with it for a while until I found (in my opinion) some pretty nice examples. A couple of minutes after I posted my solution the OP deleted the post, so I decided to ask-and-answer the question myself to share the examples.

---

### Questions:

*(a)* A function with exactly two horizontal asymptotes and exactly two vertical asymptotes, but is defined everywhere else on $\mathbb{R}$.

*(b)* A continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ with $f(2)=−3$, $f(−3)=2$, and whose graph has no -intercept.

*(c)* An everywhere continuous odd function on $\mathbb{R}$ which achieves its absolute maximum value at exactly two points.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

***a)*** A function that works is
$$
\frac{1}{x(x-1)} +\arctan(x)
$$
since the first part gives you the vertical asymptotes and the $\arctan(x)$ part gives you the horizontal ones.

[image: Example a)]

***b)*** It's impossible. Notice that at $x = -3$ you are *above* the $x$-axis (at a height of $2$) and that at $x=2$ you are *below* the $x$-axis (at a height of $-3$). If the function is continuous you should be able to draw its graph without lifting your pencil. So can you draw a line from above the $x$-axis to below the $x$-axis without lifting your pencil and without crossing the $x$-axis?

[Bolzano's theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BolzanosTheorem.html) (or the stronger [Intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)) proves the impossibility of this.

***c)*** An example that is continuous (and even differentiable) is
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
e^{2\pi+x} -1, & \text{for }\ x \le -2\pi\\
\sin(x), & \text{for }\ -2\pi<x < 2\pi\\
-e^{2\pi-x} +1, & \text{for }\ x \ge 2\pi\\
\end{cases}
$$
[image: Example c)]